# General equation definition in pyomo

Tags: pyomo

I am using pyomo and I want to define a general equation (with general variables) and then replace the specific variables, something like that:

```
def Variable_trap_eq(model, variable, f_variable, i):
    return  0 == variable[i] - variable[i+1] + (m.step/2.0)*( f_variable[i] + f_variable[i+1])

m.Variable_trap_eq_const = Constraint(m.N1, rule = Variable_trap_eq(x, f_x))
m.Variable_trap_eq_const = Constraint(m.N1, rule = Variable_trap_eq(y, f_y))
```

Something like that, where in the first constraint: variable= model.x, and f_variable = model.f_x, and in the second one: variable= model.y, and f_variable = model.f_y.

Any help?

Thanks, 
María

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way to do this would be to define two constraint rules and a third function that those two rules then call. E.g.,

```
def Variable_trap_eq(model, variable, f_variable, i):
    return  0 == variable[i] - variable[i+1] + (m.step/2.0)*(f_variable[i] + f_variable[i+1])

def Variable_trap_eq_const1_rule(model, i):
    return Variable_trap_eq(model, model.x, model.f_x, i)
m.Variable_trap_eq_const1 = Constraint(m.N1, rule=Variable_trap_eq_const1_rule)

def Variable_trap_eq_const2_rule(model, i):
    return Variable_trap_eq(model, model.y, model.f_y, i)
m.Variable_trap_eq_const2 = Constraint(m.N1, rule=Variable_trap_eq_const2_rule)
```